# How to add ability to SurfaceView to scroll in case if SurfaceView size is bigger then device screen?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have `SurfaceView` with RelativeLayouts defined as children of *root* `RelativeLayout`:

[image]

My main application contains 2 RelativeLayouts (on the top and bottom with buttons) and SurfaceView with 10 blue balls. Its seems like:

[image]

My aim is to be able to scroll SurfaceView to get other balls view and not only 1st 4 as shown on above picture. Something like:

[image]

The main point is horizontal scrollbar. People say that I can't add `SurfaceView` under `ScrollView`.

Any ideas how can I implement this?

All suggestions would be appreciated.